# php + mysql converting multiple rows into columns in a single row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a following details in my database table with columns:

```
currency code
currency rate
currency trade type
```

Eg, I had the following rows in details (database):

```
USD  3.33  buy 
USD  3.43  sell
SGD  4.33  buy
SGD  4.43  sell
```

And then, I want to bring my database tables into PHP/HTML tables as following:

```
     BUY   SELL
USD  3.33  3.43 
SGD  4.33  4.43
```

How to use looping to make them be like that?

Comment: You correctly tagged the question with the "pivot" tag -- there's numerous questions & examples.  I think you want rent-a-coder -- SO does not exist to write it for you.

Comment: @OMGPonies - It depends on who sees the question whether it will be written for you. Sometimes I will redo a simple webpage that someone has made with the `Google-Copy-Paste-?!?` method. (The code is often just plain awful, and the person is asking why something went wrong.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1.code,
    t1.rate as buy,
    t2.rate as sell
FROM currency t1
JOIN currency t2 ON t2.code = t1.code AND t2.trade_type = 'sell'
WHERE t1.trade_type = 'buy'
```

Assuming this is a currency rate table and there are no duplicates for a any (code,trade_type) pair.